# MySQL rooms availability for range

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all rooms within selected date range who have at least one available day. So if the user want to select 2014-06-15 - 2014-06-30 he should get not only rooms full available within period but also rooms which are available for one more days.

I have two tables '*rooms*' and '*rooms_booking*'

Tables:

```
rooms ( id, title, beds_number...) 

rooms_booking(id, rooms_id, start, end)
```

How should I retrieve all the rooms with criteria described above? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get the days that are taken and infer which room has at least one day available.

```
select a.title, ifnull(sum(datediff(least(b.end, '2014-06-30'), a.start) + 1),0) days_taken
from rooms a
left join rooms_booking b on a.id = b.rooms_id
where b.start >= '2014-06-15' and b.start <= '2014-06-30'
group by a.title
having days_taken <= datediff('2014-06-30', '2014-06-15');
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer but this query don't work. MIN() function accepts only one parameter. Also table 'rooms' don't have start column.

Comment: @cikabole, sorry, didn't have a sqlfiddle to test this. I meant to use `least` instead of `min`. `b.start` in both cases to get all bookings that started in the date range. they have been corrected